# can you run expect command in a bash shell script for loop

Tags: bash, shell, expect

### Goal: i have multiple linux based device on the network. i am trying to pass a password to my usernames login for multiple device. after i have logged in i want to extract information from the user. output that information to a log file on my machine. (typically a cat or tail of a log file) then i want to move on to the next device on the network. repeat until all on the network have been ran through.

#### My result:

35: xmgEXfinder.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")

here is the code i currently have:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    
    IP=$(sudo arp-scan --localnet --numeric --ignoredups --quiet | grep -i ac:3f:a4 | awk '{print$1}')
    
    Dumpdir='/home/location/logs/'
    
    for x in $IP
    do

    /usr/bin/expect<<EOF
    
    spawn ssh -i /home/location/id_rsa root@172.17.26.$x
    expect "Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa':"
    send "password\n"
    sleep 3
    log_file XMGcheck.log
    expect "~"
    send "cat /reg/nv/system/serial|sed \x22s/\x24/,/g\x22 ; tail -n 50 /usr/log/ams.log|grep -i xmg|wc -l \n"
    expect eof
    
    EOF
 
done
```

Comment: "Can"? Sure. "Should"? Certainly not. There's no compelling reason to use `expect` here; your private key is safer on password-unprotected hardware store than in a password-protected encrypted file with the password sitting in plaintext in a script.

Comment: BTW, `for x in $IP` is generally a code smell -- `readarray -t ips < <(sudo arp-scan ...)` and then `for x in "${ips[@]}"; do` would avoid string-splitting and glob-expanding your results; as it is, if you somehow got a `*` in the `IP` variable, you'd try connecting to each file in the current directory as an addres octet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a here document (`<<EOF`), the matching string must start at the beginning of a line.  You have:

```
for x in $IP
do

    /usr/bin/expect<<EOF

    spawn ssh -i /home/location/id_rsa root@172.17.26.$x
    expect "Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa':"
    send "password\n"
    sleep 3
    log_file XMGcheck.log
    expect "~"
    send "cat /reg/nv/system/serial|sed \x22s/\x24/,/g\x22 ; tail -n 50 /usr/log/ams.log|grep -i xmg|wc -l \n"
    expect eof

    EOF
```

done

You need:

```
for x in $IP
do
    /usr/bin/expect<<EOF

    spawn ssh -i /home/location/id_rsa root@172.17.26.$x
    expect "Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa':"
    send "password\n"
    sleep 3
    log_file XMGcheck.log
    expect "~"
    send "cat /reg/nv/system/serial|sed \x22s/\x24/,/g\x22 ; tail -n 50 /usr/log/ams.log|grep -i xmg|wc -l \n"
    expect eof

EOF
done
```

Or you need to use the `<<-EOF` format and then use tabs instead of spaces for identing.

You can read more in the `Here Documents` section of the [`bash` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).